# Filtering model by related model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to filter some content by related content. The trouble I'm having is that the related content hasn't necessarily been loaded when I'm trying to filter. I've tried using the `then()` function, but cannot get access to the variables outside the scope. Here's what I've tried

```
var filter = this.get('categoryFilter').toLowerCase();
App.Category.find().then(function() {
 content = this.get('content').filter(function(item) {
   return item.get('category.name').toLowerCase() === filter;
   // ERROR! filter variable doesn't exist here
  }, this);
});
```

Filtering without `then()` fails the first time, but every time after that it works, since the data is then already loaded.

Whats the best way of filtering the list?

Comment: Gevious.. Does this answer not work for you?

Comment: The question was more about how to filter within a promise, not the actual filtering itself. I had a look at the ember-data code, and I realised that I could call a controller function from within the promise context.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter a RecordArray using the filterProperty function: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterProperty

Try something like:

```
var filteredCategories = App.Category.find().filterProperty('nameLowerCase', filter);
```

In your category you will need a property to run the filter against

```
App.Category = Ember.Object.extend({

  name: '',

  nameLowerCase: function() {
    return this.get('name').toLowerCase();
  }.property('name')

});
```

Assuming that you have a CategoriesRoute which sets the model of the Categories controller to App.Category.find() then you can use the following code to get access to the filtered list from your template:

```
App.CategoriesController = Ember.Array.extend({

  filtered: function() {
    var filter = 'String value to compare lower case name to';
    return this.get('model').filterProperty('nameLowerCase', filter);

  }.property('model.@each.nameLowerCase')
});
```

Then in your template you can use:

```
{{#each filtered}}
  //Your code here
{{/each}}
```

EDIT 06/06/2013... Note that filterProperty is now called on App.Category.find()

Comment: I'm not sure you have the filterProperty class method on DS.Model, but you have DS.Model.filter() which does the same, and returning a live array. I think this could be a solution for this question (as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936956/set-controllers-content-without-model-hook) cc/ @Gevious

Comment: You're right. filterProperty is a method on the Enumerable mixin so it needs to be called on App.Category.find(). I've updated my answer to show this ..... http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterProperty

Comment: filterProperty is deprecated in favor of filterBy

https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/882